# How to shift the ring inside an aromatic ring in chemfig

Tags: chemfig

I am currently drawing the molecular structure of Benzocyclobutene (BCB).
I want it to look like this

[image: The BCB structure]

My LaTex code looks currently like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}
\begin{document}

%\setcrambond{2pt}{}{}
\chemfig{*4(-(**6(---(-[0,1]=[:-45,1]-[0,1]Si(-[:90,1]CH_3)(-O-Si(-[:90,1]CH_3)(-[:-90,1]CH_3)(-=[:45,1]- **6(---(*4(----)\quad)---)\quad ))(-[:-90,1]CH_3))--))---)\quad}

\end{document}
```

which gives the following output
[image: The result of my code]

Any good ideas how to shift the ring inside the aromatic ring? And also right group has to be rotated.

Comment: I get the following output https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qzbq1.png

Answer (score 1):

Like this? [Disclimer: I have no idea what I am doing, just played around with the angles.]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}
\begin{document}

\setcrambond{2pt}{}{}
\chemfig{*4(-(**6(---(-[0,1]=[:-45,1]-[0,1]Si(-[:90,1]CH_3)(-[:0,1]O-[:0,1]Si(-[:90,1]CH_3)(-[:-90,1]CH_3)([:0,1]-=[:45,1]-[:0] **6([:-30]---(*4(----)\quad)---)\quad ))(-[:-90,1]CH_3))--))---)\quad}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user3364924 Good to hear that the answer helped you. If you are satisfied with the solution, please consider accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark ✓, see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows others that the question is solved and will remove it from the list of unanswered questions. As a bonus, this will not only give a reward to the answer, but you will get 2 reputation points, too.